Can't resolve dependency in devDependency section after running npm install
I'm not sure if the steps I'm taking to fix my devDependency errors on upgrading my node modules are correct. I've listed the steps below and actions I took to try and correct it.
(edit) - should I just delete my node_modules folder and then run >npm install? I have my currently used one saved in my repo.
I ran >ncu -u to check and update my node modules in package.js (image below) and then ran >npm install to update but errors in devDependencies are occurring. See bottom images.
Here are my npm modules to upgrade. I'm mostly doing it to upgrade to Angular 17.


➜  client git:(master) ncu -u
Upgrading /Users/charles/yogabandy2020/client/package.json
[====================] 58/58 100%

 @angular-devkit/build-angular       ^16.2.14  →   ^17.3.4
 @angular/animations                 ^16.2.12  →   ^17.3.4
 @angular/cdk                         ^15.1.2  →   ^17.3.4
 @angular/cli                        ^16.2.14  →   ^17.3.4
 @angular/common                     ^16.2.12  →   ^17.3.4
 @angular/compiler                   ^16.2.12  →   ^17.3.4
 @angular/compiler-cli               ^16.2.12  →   ^17.3.4
 @angular/core                       ^16.2.12  →   ^17.3.4
 @angular/forms                      ^16.2.12  →   ^17.3.4
 @angular/google-maps                 ^15.2.9  →   ^17.3.4
 @angular/localize                   ^16.2.12  →   ^17.3.4
 @angular/platform-browser           ^16.2.12  →   ^17.3.4
 @angular/platform-browser-dynamic   ^16.2.12  →   ^17.3.4
 @angular/router                     ^16.2.12  →   ^17.3.4
 @auth0/angular-jwt                    ^5.1.2  →    ^5.2.0
 @cloudinary/ng                       ^1.11.2  →    ^2.0.2
 @cloudinary/url-gen                   ^1.9.2  →   ^1.19.0
 @fortawesome/fontawesome-free         ^6.2.1  →    ^6.5.2
 @stripe/stripe-js                    ^1.48.0  →    ^3.3.0
 @types/jasmine                        ^4.3.1  →    ^5.1.4
 @types/jasminewd2                    ^2.0.10  →   ^2.0.13
 @types/lodash                      ^4.14.191  →   ^4.17.0
 @types/node                        ^18.11.18  →  ^20.12.7
 @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin     ^5.49.0  →    ^7.6.0
 @typescript-eslint/parser            ^5.49.0  →    ^7.6.0
 bootstrap                             ^5.2.3  →    ^5.3.3
 eslint                               ^8.32.0  →    ^9.0.0
 eslint-plugin-html                    ^7.1.0  →    ^8.1.0
 heic2any                              ^0.0.3  →    ^0.0.4
 jasmine-core                          ~4.5.0  →    ~5.1.2
 karma                                 ~6.4.1  →    ~6.4.3
 karma-chrome-launcher                 ~3.1.1  →    ~3.2.0
 karma-jasmine-html-reporter           ^2.0.0  →    ^2.1.0
 luxon                                 ^3.2.1  →    ^3.4.4
 ng-gallery                            ^8.0.2  →   ^11.0.0
 ngx-bootstrap                        ^10.2.0  →   ^12.0.0
 ngx-image-cropper                     ^6.3.2  →    ^7.2.1
 ngx-mask                             ^15.0.3  →   ^17.0.7
 ngx-stripe                           ^15.5.0  →   ^17.2.0
 rxjs                                  ~7.8.0  →    ~7.8.1
 swiper                                ^8.4.7  →   ^11.1.1
 ts-node                              ~10.9.1  →   ~10.9.2
 tslib                                 ^2.5.0  →    ^2.6.2
 typescript                            ^4.9.4  →    ^5.4.5
 zone.js                              ^0.13.0  →   ^0.14.4

Run npm install to install new versions.
➜  client git:(master) ✗ 



Here is my modified npm package.js file after running >ncu -u


{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/google-maps": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/localize": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.4",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.2.0",
    "@cloudinary/ng": "^2.0.2",
    "@cloudinary/url-gen": "^1.19.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.5.2",
    "@ngneat/content-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^3.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "heic2any": "^0.0.4",
    "image-filters": "^1.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "luxon": "^3.4.4",
    "ng-gallery": "^11.0.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^12.0.0",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^7.2.1",
    "ngx-mask": "^17.0.7",
    "ngx-stripe": "^17.2.0",
    "ngx-webcam": "^0.4.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.1",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "tz-lookup": "^6.1.25",
    "zone.js": "^0.14.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "^5.1.4",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.13",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/node": "^20.12.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.6.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.6.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^8.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "swiper": "^11.1.1",
    "ts-node": "~10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5"
  }
}



Next I ran >npm install and I see this error below so I changed
"eslint": "^9.0.0" to "eslint": "^8.56.0", and that seemed to fix this error.


➜  client git:(master) ✗ npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: client@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: eslint@9.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   dev eslint@"^9.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint@"^8.56.0" from @typescript-eslint/parser@7.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@typescript-eslint/parser
npm ERR!   dev @typescript-eslint/parser@"^7.6.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @typescript-eslint/parser@"^7.0.0" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@7.6.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm ERR!     dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^7.6.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/charles/.npm/_logs/2024-04-13T01_02_45_312Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/charles/.npm/_logs/2024-04-13T01_02_45_312Z-debug-0.log
➜  client git:(master) ✗ 



Then I ran >npm install again and saw this error below so I changed "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.4", to "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.0.0", but that didn't seem to fix the error.


➜  client git:(master) ✗ npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: client@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^17.3.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^17.3.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@17.3.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^17.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@17.3.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^17.3.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/charles/.npm/_logs/2024-04-13T01_27_59_149Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/charles/.npm/_logs/2024-04-13T01_27_59_149Z-debug-0.log
➜  client git:(master) ✗ 



